# Select eliminado um registro e buscando outros com o mesmo código

Tags: php, mysql, select, where

O código do produto eu passo para o sql via php.

Por exemplo $cd_produto = 2; Gostaria de listar tudo menos o registro desse produto (cd_produto != 2).

Até aí tudo bem.

Porem também gostaria apenas os registros da tabela (tabela_produto) com o código da categoria desse produto (2).

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabela_produto 
WHERE cd_produto != 2  AND cd_categoria = (como saber o código da categoria desse produto que foi eliminada)
```

Comment: O `cd_categoria` é na mesma tabela do `cd_produto`?

Comment: Sim na mesma tabela.

Comment: `select * FROM tabela_produto WHERE cd_produto != 2 AND cd_categoria = (select cd_categoria where cd_produto = 2 )`. Tente isso, e me diga se é isso que tu quer realmente

Comment: Certo! Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_produto WHERE cd_produto != 2 AND 
cd_categoria = (select cd_categoria from tabela_produto where cd_produto = 2 )
```

Comment: É isso mesmo! Muito Obrigado.